# How to display Sequelize validation error messages in Express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I have this Organization model used in a Node.js/Express API with Sequelize ORM running MySQL. When I violate the 2-100 character rule under `validation` in the first code example below I get the classic `err` item from the catch block in the second code example, which doesn't contain any information about the validation error.

I would like instead to display the validation error message you can see under `validation { len: { msg: ...}}` in the model. At least console.log it, and then later display it to the end user.

However, the Sequelize manual and any other information I can find don't explain how I make use of this custom error message. So my question is how can I make use of it and display it.

Model:

```
'use strict'

const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const db = require('./../config/db.js')

const Organization = db.define('organizations', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      isUUID: {
        args: 4,
        msg: 'The ID must be a UUID4 string'
      }
    }
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    required: true,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      len: {
        args: [2, 100],
        msg: 'The name must contain between 2 and 100 characters.' // Error message I want to display
      }
    }
  },
  created_at: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    required: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    required: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  deleted_at: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE
  }
},
{
  underscored: true,
  paranoid: true,
  tableName: 'organizations',
  updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  createdAt: 'created_at',
  deletedAt: 'deleted_at'
})

module.exports = Organization
```

Controller:

```
/**
 *  @description Create new organization
 *  @route POST /api/v1/organizations
 */

exports.createOrganization = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const org = await Organization.create(
      req.body,
      {
        fields: ['name', 'type']
      })
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: {
        id: org.id,
        name: org.name
      },
      msg: `${org.name} has been successfully created.`
    })
  } catch (err) {
    next(new ErrorResponse(`Sorry, could not save the new organization`, 404))

// ^ This is the message I get if I violate the validation rule ^

  }
}
```

The Sequelize documentation for validation and constraints is found here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html

The validation is built on Validatorjs (https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js) which unfortunately also lacks practical info on the use of the validation object. I guess that means it must be self explanatory, but as I'm a noob I am lost.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I tried your same validation on my local project on `firstName` field and I could get sequelize error like this

```js
console.log('err.name', err.name);
console.log('err.message', err.message);
console.log('err.errors', err.errors);
err.errors.map(e => console.log(e.message)) // The name must contain between 2 and 100 characters.
```

[image: validation output]

as you can see you can check if `err.name` is `SequelizeValidationError` and then loop over `err.errors` array and get `message` for field on `path` and rest other properties are also there.

Error Display example:

```js
const errObj = {};
err.errors.map( er => {
   errObj[er.path] = er.message;
})
console.log(errObj);
```

you'll get an object like

```js
{ 
  firstName: 'The firstName must contain between 2 and 100 characters.',
  lastName: 'The lastName must contain between 2 and 100 characters.' 
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. So it is pushed on to the generic err object I see, and I can check first before throwing the generic error if there is an err.name property that matches SequelizeValidationError and if so display that error instead. Perfect!

Comment: Your error message is clean, when I try it, it's like  `users.name must contain between 2 and 100 characters.`   Where the `users` is the table name. Any idea how to change that ?

Comment: @ShashankAC Use the `msg` property. F.e. `isInt: {
  msg: "Must be an integer number of pennies"
}`

Answer (score 4):

After getting help from @Rohit Ambre my catch block is like this:

```
} catch (err) {
    if (err.name === 'SequelizeValidationError') {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        msg: err.errors.map(e => e.message)
      })
    } else {
      next(new ErrorResponse(`Sorry, could not save ${req.body.name}`, 404))
    }
  }
```

API response:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "msg": [
        "The name must contain between 2 and 100 characters.",
        "The organization type is not valid."
    ]
}
```

It would maybe helpful to add a key for each item, something like this, but whatever I do in the catch block it seems to give me an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:

```
catch (err) {
    if (err.name === 'SequelizeValidationError') {
       const errors = err.errors

      const errorList = errors.map(e => {
        let obj = {}
        obj[e] = e.message
        return obj;
      })
      
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        msg: errorList
      })
    } else {
      next(new ErrorResponse(`Sorry, could not save ${req.body.name}`, 404))
    }
  }
```

Any tips, por favor?

Comment: I have updated my answer with error formatting, check if that helps

Answer (score 1):

you can execute a simple flag --debug in the migration
**npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --debug**

Answer (score 1):

backend

```
response.err(res, err.errors[0].message ?? 'tidak berhasil menambahkan data', 500);
```

frontend

```
.catch(error => {
....
        this.fetchLoading = false
        this.$swal({
          title: 'Error!',
          text: `${error.response.data.message ?? 'except your message'}`,
```

```
"sequelize": "^6.6.5",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
```