# Remove sensitive Sequelize error messages in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, backend, crud

I have a bunch of sequelize models defined for my database. We are using Express to create CRUD APIs to handle db operations and the UI will call these APIs for the user interaction. Now my biggest concern is returning appropriate error messages to the user. UI can simply render the error response that these backend APIs return. This becomes challenging when the uncleaned error messages are sensitive and may expose underlying functionality to the outside world.

These are the different types of errors I am experiencing:

1.

```
errors: [
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'Student.CourseID cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'CourseID',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [Student],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }]
```

2. 

```
name: 'SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError',
parent: RequestError: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Org_Student". The conflict occurred in database "school", table "dbo.Course", column 'CourseID'.
```

3. 

```
AggregateError
[errors]: [
    RequestError: Invalid column name 'createdAt'.
    ...
]
```

4. 

```
name: 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError',
  errors: [],
  parent: RequestError: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Students' with unique index 'I_Name'. The duplicate key value is (John Doe).
```

Some error messages can be directly accessed through `error.message` and some are `AggregateErrors` embedded inside `error.parent`. So, this was roughly my code:

```
if (err instanceof UniqueConstraintError) {
    // Send a generic conflict error
} else if (err instanceof ValidationError || err instanceof ForeignKeyConstraintError) {
    // Send a generic invalid request error
} else if (err instanceof DatabaseError) {
    // Send internal server error
}
```

**EDIT:** Adding a 5th one.

5.

```
name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
parent: RequestError: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StudentName', table 'schooldb.dbo.Students'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

Why is this not under `ValidationError`? It's crazy how these errors are all over the place.

These response messages don't reveal any specific details as to what caused those errors. Meaning if somebody put the `firstName` as blank, the response should say `firstName cannot be null`. There could be 20-30 fields and multiple foreign keys and providing only generic error responses similar to the code block makes the user interaction really inefficient.

I had earlier started off following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63858084/12694601) to return to the caller. **But this does not solve the fact that some of the error messages reveal sensitive information of the database, table, and/or constraints.**

Is there a better/efficient way to handle all these cases?

Answer (score 1):

Consider defining custom error classes that extend JavaScript's Error class. These custom error classes can carry specific error codes or identifiers that your front end can understand and display appropriate messages to the user.

```js
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(message, code) {
    super(message)
    this.name = this.constructor.name
    this.code = code
  }
}
```

When handling Sequelize errors, map them to your custom error classes. This allows you to abstract away the database-specific details while providing meaningful error codes/messages to the front end.

```js
function mapSequelizeError(err) {
  if (err instanceof Sequelize.UniqueConstraintError) {
    return new CustomError('Conflict: Duplicate entry', 'CONFLICT')
  } else if (err instanceof Sequelize.ValidationError) {
    // extract specific validation errors and construct a user-friendly message
    const errors = err.errors.map(error => `${error.path} ${error.message}`)
    return new CustomError(`Invalid request: ${errors.join(', ')}`, 'VALIDATION_ERROR')
  } else if (err instanceof Sequelize.ForeignKeyConstraintError) {
    return new CustomError('Invalid request: Foreign key constraint violated', 'FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT_ERROR')
  } else {
    return new CustomError('Internal server error', 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR')
  }
}
```

Then implement an error handling middleware in your Express app to catch and format errors before sending responses.

```js
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // map Sequelize errors to custom errors
  const customError = mapSequelizeError(err)

  // log the error for debugging purposes
  console.error(err)

  // send the appropriate response to the client
  res.status(500).json({
    error: {
      message: customError.message,
      code: customError.code
    }
  })
})
```

This way your front end can check the code property of the error object returned by the API to determine the type of error and display relevant messages to the user. This approach abstracts away the database-specific details while providing informative feedback to the user.
**EDIT:** To address the concern of potentially revealing sensitive information such as table names in error messages while still providing informative feedback to the user, you can consider further refining your error handling approach.

Instead of directly exposing the table and column names in error messages, you can customize the error messages to be more generic yet informative. For example, instead of "Student.CourseID cannot be null, you can generalize it to "Course ID is required.
Create a mapping between Sequelize error types and user-friendly error messages in your code. This mapping can be maintained separately and used to translate specific Sequelize errors into more generic and user-friendly messages.
Then Before sending error messages to the front end, you can sanitize them to remove any potentially sensitive information. This can be done by parsing and filtering the error messages to ensure they do not expose any internal details. 
you can modify your error handling code to something like this,

```js
// ...mapping of Sequelize error types to user-friendly error messages
const errorMessages = {
  'notNull Violation': 'is required',
  'unique': 'must be unique',
  // ...add more mappings for other Sequelize error types as needed
}

// ...function to map Sequelize errors to custom error messages
function mapSequelizeError(err) {
  if (err instanceof Sequelize.UniqueConstraintError) {
    return new CustomError('Conflict: Duplicate entry', 'CONFLICT')
  } else if (err instanceof Sequelize.ValidationError) {
    // ...extract specific validation errors and construct a user-friendly message
    const errors = err.errors.map(error => {
      const errorMessage = errorMessages[error.type] || 'is invalid'
      return `${error.path} ${errorMessage}`
    })
    return new CustomError(`Invalid request: ${errors.join(', ')}`, 'VALIDATION_ERROR')
  } else if (err instanceof Sequelize.ForeignKeyConstraintError) {
    return new CustomError('Invalid request: Foreign key constraint violated', 'FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT_ERROR')
  } else {
    return new CustomError('Internal server error', 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR')
  }
}

// ...error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // ...map Sequelize errors to custom errors
  const customError = mapSequelizeError(err)

  // ...log the error for debugging purposes
  console.error(err)

  // ...send the appropriate response to the client
  res.status(500).json({
    error: {
      message: customError.message,
      code: customError.code
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: This solution sends generic errors like: `('Conflict: Duplicate entry', 'CONFLICT')` and `('Invalid request: Foreign key constraint violated', 'FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT_ERROR')` and also `${error.message}` which according to my example would return `Student.CourseID cannot be null`. This contains the table name. I know not every requirement can be satisfied but I am looking for a middle ground

Comment: I have updated my answer. tbh this is turning out to be a bit more complex than I initially assumed. I need to to reproduce this and work on it a bit to figure this out. Will try my best to get back to this soon again. but do give some thought on my revised version. good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just a small nit, the message `Student.CourseID cannot be null` is the default message sent from sequelize. But for the rest of the part, I agree. Will need to parse and manipulate the messages manually to redact sensitive information.

Comment: I added one more validation error but it shows up under the generic `SequelizeDatabaseError`.